Only using a lagged predictor in a regression model and not the unlagged?
Is it ever common in statistical regression models to only use the lagged value of a predictor?  e.g.

Option 1

$$
s_{t} = f(i_{t}, i_{t-1}, u_{t}, u_{t-1})
$$

Option 2

$$
s_{t} = f(i_{t}, u_{t})
$$
where $s_{t}$ are sales at time $t$, while $i_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ are inflation and unemployment at time $t$.
My logic is that perhaps the previous time period's information is more relevant at describing sales compared to the current time period's? Is Option 2 a common practice in statistical analysis modelling? Or is having the non-lagged variable as well obligatory (Option 1)?

In Option 2, the assumption is probably that the sales at time $t$ are too close time wise to inflation at time $t$ so it can't be used in practice. I think that would have to be the reason because, otherwise, if the issue described does not exist, then you may as well use it, if you are using the lagged version of it.

sorry, my my mistakes. thank you

Hi: I don't think you made a mistake. The question is quite reasonable IMHO.

This is a choice you would have to make (as an expert on the subject). As pointed out in the comments, the immediate issue here is that predicting $s_{t}$ (sales at time $t$) by using $i_{t}$ and $u_{t}$ (inflation and unemployment at time t) might not be possible because these value might not be available to you. Imagine that you would have to run your model on 5th of February but the monthly inflation and unemployment reports come out on the 20th of February. You don't have the information. Even if it's on the same date, you have the issue.
One way to approach this is to check if there's any predictive power from the lagged variables. For example, you could plot (or checks correlations) between $s_{t}$ and $i_{t-1}$ and $u_{t-1}$ and any other consecutive lags (e.g., $i_{t-n}$). If using consecutive lags, it's important to first regress and checks the predictive power on the residuals instead. For example:
$$
e_{t} = s_{t} - f(i_{t-1}, u_{t-1}) \\
corr(e_{t}, u_{t-2})= ?
$$
You could do this recursively until you find the lags with most predictive power.
Another option would be to use some criterion like Akaike's or Bayesian's criterion to check whether adding additional lags would result in a better likelihood.
To answer your question directly, however, Option 2 is used when you are trying to explain the relationship, while Option 1 could be used when you are trying to predict.

thank you for this logical answer! :)

No problem. If you are satisfied by the answer, please accept it :)
